# How to deal with Null Values in OUTER JOINS using Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I need to process the query at the bottom of this post in C#. The query works, but I don't know how to use it in EF6. I used a method and a viewmodel for it (variable query = the query below). But when it encounters null values in the OUTER JOIN, int32 cant accept this value when calling .toList(). What's the best way to deal with it?

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<TourQueryViewModel>(query);
var reslist = result.ToList();
```

I tried my first steps with LINQ, but I dont get it how to translate into LINQ itself or the query-methods, that are equivalent to it. So I am hoping for your help.

```
SELECT toursdata.TourId AS TourId, toursdata.Tourname AS Tourname,toursdata.Tourdate Tourdate,
             toursdata.VehicleId AS VehicleId, toursdata.VehicleName AS VehicleName, toursdata.LicenseNumber AS LicenseNumber, 
             Employees.EmployeeId AS EmployeeId, Employees.Gender AS Gender, Employees.Forename AS Forename, Employees.Surname AS Surname 
              FROM (
                 SELECT te.TourId, te.Tourname, te.Tourdate, 
                 Vehicles.VehicleId, Vehicles.VehicleName, Vehicles.LicenseNumber, 
                 TourEmployees.EmployeeId 
                 FROM TourEmployees RIGHT OUTER JOIN Tours AS te ON TourEmployees.TourId = te.TourId,
                 Tours AS tv INNER JOIN Vehicles ON tv.VehicleId = Vehicles.VehicleId 
                  WHERE tv.TourId = te.TourId 
              ) toursdata 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees ON toursdata.EmployeeId = Employees.EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the null problem, I changed the data type of the corresponding entity-attribute to a **nullable-type**

int turned to **int?**.

Didnt know about that language feature.